# Atributo "display" fica trocando sem parar, a ideia era que trocasse apenas 1 vez e parasse. (fadeIn e fadeOut com JS puro)

Tags: javascript

Peguei esse código de fadeIn e fadeOut com Javascript puro na internet e dei uma pequena adaptada, porém estou com um problema.

Eu tenho um card de fazer login aparecendo pro usuario, caso ele clique no botão "CRIAR CONTA", o card de login desaparece e o card de criar conta aparece, isso está funcionando, o problema é na hora de voltar, caso o usuario clique no botão "VOLTAR", o card de criar conta desaparece e o card de login volta a aparecer, porem se eu olhar no "Inspecionar Elemento" do Firefox, eu vejo que a propriedade `display` fica alterando sem parar, fica alternando sem parar entre `display: block` e `display: none`, tanto no card de login como no card de criar conta, a ideia era de que o card de criar conta recebesse apenas 1 vez o `display: none` (pra sumir) e o card de login recebesse apenas 1 vez o `display: block` (pra voltar a aparecer), porém fica alternando entre `display: block` e `display: none` infinitamente bem rapido.
O card fica piscando. (porque esta alternando bem rapido a propriedade `display`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cinema</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fadeOut(id, time) {
            fade(id, time, 100, 0, 0);
        }

        function fadeIn(id, time) {
            fade(id, time, 0, 100, 1);
        }

        function fade(id, time, ini, fin, inout) {
            timer = (time * 1000) / 50;
            if(inout == 1)
            {
                setInterval(function(){ document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block"; }, timer);
            }
            var target = document.getElementById(id);
            var alpha = ini;
            var inc;
            if (fin >= ini) { 
                inc = 2; 
            } else {
                inc = -2;
            }
            var i = setInterval(
                function() {
                    if ((inc > 0 && alpha >= fin) || (inc < 0 && alpha <= fin)) {
                        clearInterval(i);
                    }
                    setAlpha(target, alpha);
                    alpha += inc;
                }, timer);
            if(inout == 0)
            {
                setInterval(function(){ document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none"; }, timer);
            }   
        }

        function setAlpha(target, alpha) {
            target.style.filter = "alpha(opacity="+ alpha +")";
            target.style.opacity = alpha/100;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">
    <div class="cardLogin" id="cardLogin">
        <div class="tituloCardLogin">
            <span><i class="mdi mdi-movie mdi-48px"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="inputCardLogin" id="inputCardLogin">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <br><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="btnCardLogin">
            <button type="button">LOGIN</button><br>
            <button type="button" onclick="irCriarConta()">CRIAR CONTA</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cardCriarConta" id="cardCriarConta">
        <div class="tituloCardCriarConta">
            <span><i class="mdi mdi-movie mdi-48px"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="inputCardCriarConta" id="inputCriarConta">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <br><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <br><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        </div>
        <div class="btnCardCriarConta">
            <button type="button" onclick="voltarLogin()">VOLTAR</button><br>
            <button type="button">SALVAR</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function irCriarConta() {
        fadeOut("cardLogin", 1.2);
        fadeIn("cardCriarConta", 1.2);
    }

    function voltarLogin() {
        fadeIn("cardLogin", 3);
        fadeOut("cardCriarConta", 3);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Card Login:

[image: Card Login]

Card Criar Conta:

[image: Card Criar Conta]

Comment: Vc tem 3 setIntervals, está matando apenas 1 (o que tem o nome de `i`), logo os outros 2 vão ficar rodando infinitamente, porque o setInterval é infinito até que vc o mate. Isso está causando conflito grave no código.

Comment: Está um pouco dificil analisar o seu código por que não posso ver o efeito sem os arquivos CSS, eu fiquei confuso com a necessidade do uso do `setInterval`, eu particulamente trocaria apenas a propriedade `display` e `opacity` (tem que colocar mais atributos pra diferentes navegadores) para dar o efeito, eu fiz uma navegação por ABAs simuladas dessa maneira.


Aguardando, se puder use o https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Fiz uma melhora no código bem na hora que vc votou. Não sei se chegou a ver. O código ficou bem melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `setInterval` cria um temporizador infinito até que você o cancele através do `clearInterval`. Ao chamá-los várias vezes sem o devido cancelamento, irá criar um gargalo de `setIntervals` rodando ao mesmo tempo.

Para solucionar isso, você teria que dar um nome a cada um e usar o `clearInterval` no fim do processo para cancelar cada um.

Mas analisando o seu código, percebi que está usando `setInterval` em excesso, quando poderia usar apenas um:

Veja no exemplo abaixo como fica mais simples usando apenas 1 `setInterval`:

```js
function fadeOut(id, time) {
   fade(id, time, 100, 0, 0);
}

function fadeIn(id, time) {
   fade(id, time, 0, 100, 1);
}

function fade(id, time, ini, fin, inout) {
   timer = (time * 1000) / 50;
   var target = document.getElementById(id);
   var alpha = ini;
   var inc = fin >= ini ? 2 : -2;
   var i = setInterval(
       function() {
           target.style.display = inout == 1 ? "block" : "none";
           if ((inc > 0 && alpha >= fin) || (inc < 0 && alpha <= fin)) {
               clearInterval(i);
           }
           setAlpha(target, alpha);
           alpha += inc;
       }, timer);
}

function setAlpha(target, alpha) {
   target.style.filter = "alpha(opacity="+ alpha +")";
   target.style.opacity = alpha/100;
}

function irCriarConta() {
        fadeOut("cardLogin", 1.2);
        fadeIn("cardCriarConta", 1.2);
    }

    function voltarLogin() {

        fadeIn("cardLogin", 3);
        fadeOut("cardCriarConta", 3);
    }
```

```css
#cardCriarConta{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardLogin" id="cardLogin">
        <div class="tituloCardLogin">
            <span><i class="mdi mdi-movie mdi-48px"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="inputCardLogin" id="inputCardLogin">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <br><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="btnCardLogin">
            <button type="button">LOGIN</button><br>
            <button type="button" onclick="irCriarConta()">CRIAR CONTA</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cardCriarConta" id="cardCriarConta">
        <div class="tituloCardCriarConta">
            <span><i class="mdi mdi-movie mdi-48px"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="inputCardCriarConta" id="inputCriarConta">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <br><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <br><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        </div>
        <div class="btnCardCriarConta">
            <button type="button" onclick="voltarLogin()">VOLTAR</button><br>
            <button type="button">SALVAR</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @dvd corrigiu meu problema. Vlw mesmo! Em relação a usar apenas 1 `setInterval`, eu não postei o CSS, mas os cards possuem um `display: none` e `display: block`, ai eu preciso é ir desaparecendo com uma div e até sumir e depois ir aparecendo outra div até aparecer por completo, eu usei mais 2 `setInterval` pra conseguir colocar a propriedade `display` em cada card e isso não acontecer de maneira brusca, e sim acontecer logo que acabar o fade, por isso um `setInterval` pra cada.